# Writing the group over cyclotomic fields in GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap, cyclotomic-fields

I am able to define the group and do something with this group in GAP. For example, I am interested in the 2I group, and I can write this group in GAP simply as follows:

```
gens_ := GeneratorsOfGroup(SL(2,5)); # the subgroup you are interested in
Print(gens_);
```

The generators are given as:

```
[ [ [ Z(5), 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^3 ] ], 
  [ [ Z(5)^2, Z(5)^0 ], [ Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ] ] ]
```

Now, how can I find the generators of this group in terms of a cyclotomic field rather then in terms of Z(5)? Alternatively, once I find the generators of the group, are there any ways to express them over a cyclotomic field?

Thank you in advance.